# Add user to tomcat-users.xml with xsltproc (XSL stylesheet)

Tags: tomcat, xslt

I am trying to add a Tomcat user to `$CATALINE_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` in a `bash` script with `xsltproc` as follows (`tomcat-users.xml` is the default version that ships with Apache Tomcat 9):

```
xsltproc --stringparam username test1 \
         --stringparam password test2 \
         add-tomcat-user.xslt tomcat-users.xml
```

It is *almost* working with this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- (unmodified comments -->
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instaance">
<!-- (unmodified comments -->
<user username="$username" password="$password" roles="manager-gui"/></tomcat-users>
```

My XSLT file `add-tomcat-users.xslt` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:tomcat="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml">
                xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="username"/>
   <xsl:param name="password"/>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="tomcat:tomcat-users">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
       <user username="$username" password="$password" roles="manager-gui"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Three issues remain:

- The XSL parameters are not properly substituted. Why (despite `xsl:param`)?
- The indentation of the inserted element is not right? Why (despite `indent="yes"`)?
- Can I avoid having to define the same namespace twice (once for prefix `tomcat` and once as default namespace) while `<xsl:template match="tomcat:tomcat-users">` still succeeding and the output still using the `http://tomcat.apache.org/xml` as same default namespace?

So how can I remain those addressing issues (by changing my `add-tomcat-user.xslt` or command line options to `xsltproc`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute value templates `<tomcat:user username="{$username}" password="{$password}" roles="manager-gui"/>` to set the attribute values. You can simply use `<user username="{$username}" password="{$password}" roles="manager-gui"/>` however given the default namespace declaration in the XSLT.

As for not declaring the same namespace twice, even with an XSLT 2.0 processor you would need to use two attributes, one saying `xpath-default-namespace="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"` (which then would allow you to use `<xsl:template match="tomcat-users">...</xsl:template>`), the other declaring the default namespace for the result elements the way you have (`xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"`). So I don't think there is a clean way to avoid what you have, unless you want to use `<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'tomcat-users' and namespace-uri() = 'http://tomcat.apache.org/xml']">...</xsl:template>` or `<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'tomcat-users']">...</xsl:template>`. So that does not gain you much of a simplification and might be less efficient in terms of matching.

Comment: Excellent. That takes care of the 1st issue. (I already had `<user ...>` -- typo).

Comment: @Drux, I have added a paragraph on the namespace issue, but I don't think there is a simple reduction of code possible given that input namespace matching and result element namespace declaration are different tasks in XSLT.

Comment: Thx, I'll accept the answer because indentation (and even redundant namespace definitions) are only syntactic sugar. The result can already be used after fixing the 1st issue thanks to your answer.